# Bazel include file not found

Tags: c++, bazel

**Edit (2022-05-28):** for anyone who ends up here from searching for bazel + sfml, I gave up on trying to compile it from source with bazel.

Instead, I installed SFML with brew. Then in `WORKSPACE.bazel`:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "SFML",
    path = "/opt/homebrew",
    build_file = "third_party/SFML/BUILD.bazel"
)
```

and `third_party/SFML/BUILD.bazel`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "sfml",
    srcs = glob(["lib/libsfml-*.dylib"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/SFML/**/*.*"]),
    include_prefix = "SFML",
    strip_include_prefix = "include/SFML",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

finally, as a dependency in any BUILD.bazel:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    deps = [
        "@SFML//:sfml",
    ]
)
```

This allows me to `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` for example in `main.cc` and so far it's working.

---

I'm trying to use bazel to build SFML from source and use it in a project. Right now I have a very simple setup:

```
foo/
  src/
    main.cc
    BUILD
  third_party/
    SFML/
      ...
      BUILD
    BUILD
  WORKSPACE
```

```
# third_party/SFML/BUILD

load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "sfml",
    srcs = glob(["src/*.cpp"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/*.hpp"]),
    copts = ["-Ithird_party/SFML/include"],
    linkopts = [
        "-lsfml‑system",
        "-lsfml‑window",
        "-lsfml‑graphics",
        "-lsfml‑audio",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

```
# src/BUILD

load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")

cc_binary(
    name = "mygame",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    deps = [
        "//third_party/SFML:sfml",
    ],
)
```

and `main.cc`:

```
#include "third_party/SFML/sfml/Graphics.hpp"
#include "third_party/SFML/sfml/System.hpp"
#include "third_party/SFML/sfml/Window.hpp"

int main() {
  // ...
}
```

When I run `bazel build //src:mygame` I get an error:

```
fatal error: 'third_party/SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found
```

I also tried using `#include "third_party/SFML/Graphics.hpp"` but that doesn't work either.

Not sure what the correct include path needs to be. Any suggestions?

Comment: It’s whatever the actual path to the file is. Looks to me like you’re missing `include` in your path to the file, based on how you’re globbing them

Comment: @Taekahn any suggestions on globbing it correctly?

Comment: Sorry, what i mean is it looks like the line should be `#include "third_party/SFML/include/Graphics.hpp"` but without seeing the actual file structure i can only guess. It should be whatever the actual path to the file should be from the project root.

Comment: Just taking a guess here but copts = ["-Ithird_party/SFML/include"], looks to me like it should be copts = ["-Ithird_party/SFML/sfml"], but bazel haunts my dreams so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the project structure of SFML, the glob pattern is not capturing any targets as the files are nested inside another folder named **SFML**.

Inspecting the bazel target lists only two targets in your case. Running

```
bazel query '@SFML//:sfml'
```

Will output two targets.

- @SFML//:sfml
- @SFML//::BUILD.bazel

Which means your library is empty when it is built. Hence importing the header files are not found.

You can update the rule to

```
cc_library(
  name = "sfml",
  srcs = glob(["src/SFML/**/*.cpp", "src/SFML/**/*.hpp"]),
  hdrs = glob(["include/SFML/**/*.hpp", "include/SFML/**/*.inl"]),
  strip_include_prefix = "include",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

to make it work. I have added another entry in glob patterns as SFML have inl files & private header files.

I am also new to stackoverflow, I hope my answer helps you or atleast gives you a direction.